# ¿Cómo puedo centrar en una página en Latex de forma vertical? Es decir que vaya en el centro de la página en ese sentido

Tags: latex

Estoy haciendo un trabajo de investigación y quiero que en la primera página solo se vea el título con datos como la fecha y mi nombre pero solo eso. Y en la siguiente página iniciar el cuerpo del trabajo. Entonces quiero que en la primera página solo se vea este título pero centrado en medio de la página tanto de forma vertical como horizontal.

Comment: Bienvenido Emilio Sebastian Daza Vigo a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Agrega por favor un ejemplo de código de lo que intentas hace, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

A continuación se muestra una forma sencilla de centrar verticalmente una `titlepage`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\phantom{}
\vfill
\begin{center}
{\Huge Title of the work}

\vspace{1cm}

{\huge Author name}

\vspace{1cm}

{\Large \today}
\end{center}
\vfill
\phantom{}
\end{titlepage}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Lo siento pero solo hablo italiano y utilicé el traductor de Google :)